# attempting to copy non zero rows and also create a report template

Tags: excel, vba

I have two inclusions I want to include in this code.

The first is to omit zero balance values (in column F in TB New) rows from my TB New and paste rows to TB New Non Zero, I will just change the input worksheet from TB New to TB New Non Zero. I was thinking of just repeating this code but changing it to new variables and just do Cell Value <> 0 but I tried it and it didnt work:

```
    Dim xTb As Range
    Dim xTbCell As Range
    Dim F As Long
    Dim G As Long
    Dim H As Long
    F = Worksheets("TB New").UsedRange.Rows.Count
    G = Worksheets("TB New Non Zero").UsedRange.Rows.Count
    If G = 1 Then
    If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Worksheets("TB New Non Zero").UsedRange) = 0 Then G = 0
    End If
    Set xTb = Worksheets("TB New").Range("F1:F" & F)
    On Error Resume Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Worksheets("TB New Non Zero").UsedRange.Offset(1).Clear
    G = 0
    For H = 1 To xTb.Count
        If CStr(xTb(H).Value) <> 0 Then
            xTb(H).EntireRow.Copy Destination:=Worksheets("TB New Non Zero").Range("F" & G + 1)
            G = G + 1
        End If
    Next
```

The code above prints just all the rows and omits some rows at the bottom which is not what I want.

The second is to create a for loop where LEFT(column A Value,1) = 0 then copy the rows that are that then the next row Set value to be Expenses and then add 1 to the row then where LEFT(column A Value,1) = 1 then copy the rows then so on.

Essentially Currently it is:

```
0575 Interest 20
1015 Purchases -50
1680 Repairs -10
2000 Bank 200
2400 Debtors 0
2475 Plant 200
```

But I want it as

```
Revenue
0575 Interest 20
Expenses
1015 Purchases -50
1680 Repairs -10
Current Assets
2000 Bank 200
2475 Plant 200
```

Any help on this code? Thanks,

````
Function getLastUsedRow(ws As Worksheet) As Long

    Dim lastUsedRow As Long: lastUsedRow = 1
    On Error Resume Next
        lastUsedRow = ws.Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    getLastUsedRow = lastUsedRow

End Function
Function getLastUsedColumn(ws As Worksheet) As Long
    
    Dim lastUsedColumn As Long: lastUsedColumn = 1
    On Error Resume Next
        lastUsedColumn = ws.Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Column
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    getLastUsedColumn = lastUsedColumn

End Function
Function checkIfWorksheetExists(wb As Workbook, wsName As String) As Boolean

    Dim i As Long
    Dim found As Boolean
    
    found = False
    
    For i = 1 To wb.Worksheets.Count
    
        If Trim(wb.Worksheets(i).Name) = Trim(wsName) Then
        
            found = True
            Exit For
        
        End If
    
    Next i
    
    checkIfWorksheetExists = found

End Function
Public Function inCollection(ByVal inputCollection As Collection, ByVal inputKey As Variant) As Boolean

    On Error Resume Next
    inputCollection.Item inputKey
    inCollection = (Err.Number = 0)
    Err.Clear

End Function
Sub CopyRowBasedOnCellValue()
    Dim xRg As Range
    Dim xCell As Range
    Dim A As Long
    Dim B As Long
    Dim C As Long
    A = Worksheets("SQL hl_balance").UsedRange.Rows.Count
    B = Worksheets("CY amounts").UsedRange.Rows.Count
    If B = 1 Then
    If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Worksheets("CY amounts").UsedRange) = 0 Then B = 0
    End If
    Set xRg = Worksheets("SQL hl_balance").Range("A1:A" & A)
    On Error Resume Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Worksheets("CY amounts").UsedRange.Offset(1).Clear
    B = 4
    For C = 1 To xRg.Count
        If CStr(xRg(C).Value) = Worksheets("Client Details").Range("C19").Value Then
            xRg(C).EntireRow.Copy Destination:=Worksheets("CY amounts").Range("A" & B + 1)
            B = B + 1
        End If
    Next
    
    If Not checkIfWorksheetExists(ThisWorkbook, "Index") Then
        MsgBox "Please create Index sheet, and run macro again!"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    Dim i As Long
    Dim j As Long
    Dim k As Long

    Dim wsInputData As Worksheet: Set wsInputData = Worksheets("TB New")
    Dim wsInputDataStartingRow As Long: wsInputDataStartingRow = wsInputData.Range("C1").End(xlDown).Row + 1 ' Starting row !
    Dim wsInputDataEndingRow As Long: wsInputDataEndingRow = getLastUsedRow(wsInputData) + 10 ' Ending row !
    
    Dim wsInputDataUsedRange As Range: Set wsInputDataUsedRange = wsInputData.Range("A" & CStr(wsInputDataStartingRow) & ":" & "D" & CStr(wsInputDataEndingRow))

    Dim wsIndex As Worksheet: Set wsIndex = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Index")
    Dim wsIndexStartingRow As Long: wsIndexStartingRow = 5
    Dim wsIndexEndingRow As Long: wsIndexEndingRow = getLastUsedRow(wsIndex) + 10
    
    Dim wsIndexUsedRange As Range: Set wsIndexUsedRange = wsIndex.Range("A" & CStr(wsIndexStartingRow) & ":" & "H" & CStr(wsIndexEndingRow))
    
    Dim wsIndexSheetCollection As Collection: Set wsIndexSheetCollection = New Collection
    Dim wsIndexCellCollection As Collection: Set wsIndexCellCollection = New Collection
    Dim wsIndexCellCollection2 As Collection: Set wsIndexCellCollection2 = New Collection
    Dim wsIndexStatusCollection As Collection: Set wsIndexStatusCollection = New Collection

    For i = wsIndexStartingRow To wsIndexEndingRow

        If Trim(wsIndex.Range("A" & CStr(i)).Value2) <> "" And Trim(wsIndex.Range("E" & CStr(i)).Value2) <> "" Then

            If wsIndex.Range("E" & CStr(i)).Hyperlinks.Count > 0 Then
                
                If Not inCollection(wsIndexSheetCollection, Trim(wsIndex.Range("A" & CStr(i)).Value2)) Then
                    wsIndexSheetCollection.Add Trim(wsIndex.Range("E" & CStr(i)).Hyperlinks.Item(1).SubAddress), Trim(wsIndex.Range("A" & CStr(i)).Value2)
                    wsIndexCellCollection2.Add Trim(wsIndex.Range("E" & CStr(i)).Value2), Trim(wsIndex.Range("A" & CStr(i)).Value2)
                End If
            
            Else
            
                If Not inCollection(wsIndexSheetCollection, Trim(wsIndex.Range("A" & CStr(i)).Value2)) Then
                    wsIndexSheetCollection.Add Trim(wsIndex.Range("E" & CStr(i)).Value2), Trim(wsIndex.Range("A" & CStr(i)).Value2)
                    wsIndexCellCollection2.Add Trim(wsIndex.Range("E" & CStr(i)).Value2), Trim(wsIndex.Range("A" & CStr(i)).Value2)
                End If
            
            End If
            
        End If

        If Trim(wsIndex.Range("A" & CStr(i)).Value2) <> "" And Trim(wsIndex.Range("F" & CStr(i)).Value2) <> "" Then
            
            If Not inCollection(wsIndexCellCollection, Trim(wsIndex.Range("A" & CStr(i)).Value2)) Then
                wsIndexCellCollection.Add Trim(wsIndex.Range("F" & CStr(i)).Value2), Trim(wsIndex.Range("A" & CStr(i)).Value2)
            End If
        
        End If

        If Trim(wsIndex.Range("A" & CStr(i)).Value2) <> "" And Trim(wsIndex.Range("H" & CStr(i)).Value2) <> "" Then
            
            If Not inCollection(wsIndexStatusCollection, Trim(wsIndex.Range("A" & CStr(i)).Value2)) Then
                wsIndexStatusCollection.Add Trim(wsIndex.Range("H" & CStr(i)).Value2), Trim(wsIndex.Range("A" & CStr(i)).Value2)
            End If
        
        End If
    
    Next i

    Call Unlock_Sheet
    wsIndexUsedRange.ClearContents
    wsIndexUsedRange.Cells.Font.Bold = False

    wsInputDataUsedRange.Copy
    wsIndex.Range("A" & CStr(wsIndexStartingRow)).PasteSpecial xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
    Application.CutCopyMode = False


    wsIndexEndingRow = getLastUsedRow(wsIndex) + 100

    For i = wsIndexEndingRow To wsIndexStartingRow Step -1
    
        If Trim(wsIndex.Range("B" & CStr(i)).Value2) = "" Then
            wsIndex.Rows(CStr(i) & ":" & CStr(i)).Delete
        End If
        
    Next i

    wsIndexEndingRow = getLastUsedRow(wsIndex) + 10

    For i = wsIndexStartingRow To wsIndexEndingRow

        If Trim(wsIndex.Range("A" & CStr(i)).Value2) <> "" Then
        
            If inCollection(wsIndexSheetCollection, Trim(wsIndex.Range("A" & CStr(i)).Value2)) Then

                If InStr(1, wsIndexSheetCollection.Item(Trim(wsIndex.Range("A" & CStr(i)).Value2)), "!") <> 0 Then

                    wsIndex.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=wsIndex.Range("E" & CStr(i)), Address:="", SubAddress:=wsIndexSheetCollection.Item(Trim(wsIndex.Range("A" & CStr(i)).Value2)), TextToDisplay:="'" & Trim(wsIndex.Range("A" & CStr(i)).Value2)
                    wsIndex.Range("E" & CStr(i)).Value2 = "'" & wsIndexCellCollection2.Item(Trim(wsIndex.Range("A" & CStr(i)).Value2))
                Else

                    If checkIfWorksheetExists(ThisWorkbook, Trim(wsIndex.Range("A" & CStr(i)).Value2)) Then

                        If inCollection(wsIndexCellCollection, Trim(wsIndex.Range("A" & CStr(i)).Value2)) Then
                            wsIndex.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=wsIndex.Range("E" & CStr(i)), Address:="", SubAddress:=Trim(wsIndex.Range("A" & CStr(i)).Value2) & "!" & wsIndexCellCollection.Item(Trim(wsIndex.Range("A" & CStr(i)).Value2)), TextToDisplay:=Trim("'" & wsIndex.Range("A" & CStr(i)).Value2)
                            wsIndex.Range("E" & CStr(i)).Value2 = "'" & wsIndexCellCollection2.Item(Trim(wsIndex.Range("A" & CStr(i)).Value2))
                        Else
                            wsIndex.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=wsIndex.Range("E" & CStr(i)), Address:="", SubAddress:=Trim(wsIndex.Range("A" & CStr(i)).Value2) & "!A1", TextToDisplay:="'" & Trim(wsIndex.Range("A" & CStr(i)).Value2)
                            wsIndex.Range("E" & CStr(i)).Value2 = "'" & wsIndexCellCollection2.Item(Trim(wsIndex.Range("A" & CStr(i)).Value2))
                        End If
                    Else

                        wsIndex.Range("E" & CStr(i)).Value2 = wsIndexSheetCollection.Item(Trim(wsIndex.Range("A" & CStr(i)).Value2))
                        
                    End If
                End If
                
            End If

            If inCollection(wsIndexCellCollection, Trim(wsIndex.Range("A" & CStr(i)).Value2)) Then
                wsIndex.Range("F" & CStr(i)).Value2 = wsIndexCellCollection.Item(Trim(wsIndex.Range("A" & CStr(i)).Value2))
            End If

            wsIndex.Range("G" & CStr(i)).Formula = "=IFERROR(IF(OR(C" & CStr(i) & "+D" & CStr(i) & "=INDIRECT(""'""&E" & CStr(i) & "&""'""&""!""& F" & CStr(i) & "),D" & CStr(i) & "-C" & CStr(i) & "=INDIRECT(""'""&E" & CStr(i) & "&""'""&""!""& F" & CStr(i) & "),C" & CStr(i) & "-D" & CStr(i) & "=INDIRECT(""'""&E" & CStr(i) & "&""'""&""!""& F" & CStr(i) & ")),1,0),"""")"

            If inCollection(wsIndexStatusCollection, Trim(wsIndex.Range("A" & CStr(i)).Value2)) Then
                wsIndex.Range("H" & CStr(i)).Value2 = wsIndexStatusCollection.Item(Trim(wsIndex.Range("A" & CStr(i)).Value2))
            End If
        
        End If
    
    Next i

    Set wsIndexSheetCollection = Nothing
    Set wsIndexCellCollection = Nothing
    Set wsIndexStatusCollection = Nothing
    Set wsIndex = Nothing

Sheets("Index").Select
Range("A1").Select

    MsgBox "Done !", vbInformation
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub```


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/H1jT6.png
````

Comment: In your first example what is `xRg` ?  Are you using `Option Explicit` ?  Second one is *way* too much code to post without an explanation of what's wrong with it.  What does/doesn't it do that it's not supposed/supposed to do ?

Comment: @TimWilliams The second code is almost really good. It pastes the amounts in TB New to the Index worksheet. I just need a particular format where in the for loop, I want to have the following:

Revenue
04-09 Account Numbers (in column A)
Expenses
10-19 Account Numbers
Current Assets
20-24 Numbers
Non Current Assets
25-29
and so on